# Problem with rotate circle

Tags: iphone, xcode4, object-code

[image]

I want to rotate circle follows my finger's path.
If I move my finger more fast, then the circle must rotate fast.
If I move my finger slowly, the circle must slow.
Also circle's movement must smooth.
How can I implement this?
Please give me any help.

Comment: 4 circles are individual images.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UIPanGestureRecognizer, you can get Velocity property of recognizer and after it you can use its value in your rotation code (glRotate or smth else) to correct angle.